# Matrix linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$. Find the matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say that $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is linear and satisﬁes $T(1,1,1) = (3,2,0,1)$, $T(1,1,0) = (2,1,3, −1)$ and $T(1,0,0) =(5, −2,1,0)$. Find $T(x, y, z)$ and then ﬁnd the matrix representation for $T$.

I am not sure how to proceed. I thought of two approaches, one the matrix $A$ from $Ax=b$ could be expressed as

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 5\\
2 & 1 & -2\\
0 & 3 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then possibly solve for $Ax=0$?

Or since $T(1,0,0)=v_3$ etc, we can also write $T(x,y,z)=x\cdot v_1+y \cdot v_2+z \cdot v_3$, but I am not sure how to find $v_1$, $v_2$ or $v_3$.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: First question: What is the dimension of the matrix of this transformation?

Comment: It should be 4x3. Because we are going from R3->R4

Comment: Good, now set up this matrix, using $a,b,c,...$ letters as entries of the matrix. You can set up 3 matrix multiplications like $A*(1,1,1) = (3,2,0,1)$ etc. and this gives you a whole bunch of systems of equations which you can solve for all your entries of matrix A. A Ti calculator would be handy (use RREF)

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(0,0,1) = T(1,1,1) - T(1,1,0) = (1, 1, -3, 2)$, and $T(0,1,0) = T(1,1,0) - T(1,0,0) = (-3, 3, 2, -1)$, and $T(1,0,0) = (5, -2, 1, 0)$. So 
\begin{align*}T(x,y,z) &= xT(1,0,0) + yT(0,1,0) + zT(0,0,1) \\
&= x(5,-2,1,0) + y(-3,3,2,-1) + z(1,1,-3,2) \\
&= (5x-3y+z, -2x+3y+z, x+2y-3z, -y+2z).\end{align*} And from this the matrix $A$ is:

\begin{pmatrix}
5  & -3 & 1 \\
-2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}

You can continue.

Comment: 273 answers and still didn't learn basic latex? I think it's time. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @Cortizol: yes yes, soon on mathjax